# How to get mutability errors for FFI wrapper

Tags: rust, ffi

I am interacting with an FFI c library, writing a 'fat' layer to contain all the unsafe code. I have noticed that I do not get any warnings if I mutate data via `*mut` types.

What I would like is for the type checker to force me to have the correct ownership of the struct before calling into FFI. The problem might occur that the C API changes from

`pub fn c_thing_mutate(thing: *const c_thing);`

to

`pub fn c_thing_mutate(thing: *mut c_thing);`

and Rust will not warn that the rust API now needs to change.

Example code causing UB. `c_thing_mutate` mutates data derived from `&self`:

```rust
use std::ptr::null_mut;

#[repr(C)]
pub struct c_thing {
    _unused: [u8; 0],
}

extern "C" {
    pub fn c_thing_init(thing: *mut *mut c_thing);
    pub fn c_thing_mutate(thing: *mut c_thing);
    pub fn c_thing_release(thing: *mut c_thing);
}

struct CThingWrapper {
    thing: *mut c_thing,
}

impl CThingWrapper {
    pub fn new() -> CThingWrapper {
        let mut thing: *mut c_thing = null_mut();
        unsafe { c_thing_init(&mut thing) };
        CThingWrapper { thing }
    }

    pub fn mutate(&self) {
        unsafe { c_thing_mutate(self.thing) };
    }
}

impl Drop for CThingWrapper {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        unsafe {
            c_thing_release(self.thing);
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let x = CThingWrapper::new();
    x.mutate();
}
```

I thought Box or Cell might help me with this. Box<> is difficult as I am having trouble dropping the thing:

```rust
use std::ptr::null_mut;

#[repr(C)]
pub struct c_thing {
    _unused: [u8; 0],
}

extern "C" {
    pub fn c_thing_init(thing: *mut *mut c_thing);
    pub fn c_thing_mutate(thing: *mut c_thing);
    pub fn c_thing_release(thing: *mut c_thing);
}

struct CThingWrapper {
    thing: Box<c_thing>,
}

impl CThingWrapper {
    pub fn new() -> CThingWrapper {
        let mut thing: *mut c_thing = null_mut();
        unsafe { c_thing_init(&mut thing) };
        CThingWrapper {
            thing: unsafe { Box::from_raw(thing) },
        }
    }

    pub fn mutate(&mut self) {
        let thing = self.thing.as_mut();
        unsafe {
            c_thing_mutate(thing);
            self.thing = Box::from_raw(thing)
        };
    }
}

impl Drop for CThingWrapper {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        unsafe {
            let thing = Box::leak(self.thing);
            c_thing_release(thing);
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let x = CThingWrapper::new();
    x.mutate();
}
```

Error: "cannot move out of `self.thing` which is behind a mutable
reference, move occurs because `self.thing` has type `Box<c_thing>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait"

Box seems not quite right, Box wants to alloc and free the memory, but I need to delegate that to the C API.

Cell is not quite right; "Cell implements interior mutability by moving values in and out of the Cell.".

I suspect I might need a combo of types, for example `Option<Box<T>>`

Comment: The first code is not UB. You hold a pointer, and it's perfectly fine to mutate it, even via `&self` (pointers are, in fact, exterior mutability).

Comment: And also, borrowck isn't relevant here, this is about type checking.

Comment: Also, please specify all "troubles" you have, full errors from `cargo check`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman thanks, maybe I misunderstood this: "Mutating immutable data. All data inside a const item is immutable. Moreover, all data reached through a shared reference or data owned by an immutable binding is immutable, unless that data is contained within an UnsafeCell<U>." It specifically mentions UnsafeCell, but not *mut as the valid way to mutate data.

Comment: This is indeed a little misleading. It refers to conitguous data, not data reached through a raw pointer.

Comment: I asked this question on the rust reference github, and the user there says explicitly that this IS UB: https://github.com/rust-lang/reference/issues/1227

Comment: I think they're referring to another case, and commented accordingly.

Comment: They've confirmed what I thought - your use case is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 1):

NonNull is the type needed.

```
pub struct RustThing {
    internal_thing: NonNull<real_thing>,
}

impl RustThing {
 pub fn new() -> RustThing {
  let mut t: *mut real_thing = null_mut();
  make_thing(&mut t);
  RustThing { internal_thing: NonNull::new(t).unwrap() }
 }
}
```